# While Loop and If/Else in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, if-statement, plsql, while-loop, oracle10g

I am trying to write a procedure that will produce the following output

```
exec WinOrLose(4)

Welcome to the Win or Lose Game. Your number is 4. 

You win.
You lose.
You win.
You lose.

==> You lose!
```

So far I have this:

```
CREATE or REPLACE Procedure WinOrLose (
  p_choice number ) AS

  v_answer number;

DECLARE
  v_answer := p_choice

BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line ('Welcome to the Win or Lose Game. Your number is ' || 
  v_answer);

  FOR v_answer in 1..10 
    IF MOD(v_answer, 2) = 0 THEN -- v_answer is even
          dbms_output.put_line (You lose)

END;
/
```

I'm unsure of where to go from there. My thought process (psuedocode) is this:

```
SET v_answer := 1
   While Loop (outside)
     MOD(v_answer,2) = 0 then dbms.output (YOU LOSE)
   ELSE
     dbms.output (YOU WIN)
   end if;
     v_answer := p_choice
```

Comment: What are the rules? Looking at the code and pseudo code nothing makes any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE or REPLACE Procedure WinOrLose (
  p_choice number ) AS
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line ('Welcome to the Win or Lose Game. Your number is ' || 
  p_choice);

  FOR v_counter in 1..p_choice LOOP
    IF (MOD(v_counter, 2) = 0) 
    THEN
          dbms_output.put_line ('You win');
    ELSE
          dbms_output.put_line ('You lose');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  IF (MOD(p_choice , 2) = 0) 
  THEN
    dbms_output.put_line ('==> You win!');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line ('==> You lose!');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you! Last question, how would I output "==> You lose!" or "==> You  win!" at the end?

Comment: @Lizzie You are welcome! I have edited it, let me know if it is working. Best.

Comment: Thank you so much!